# Query about an unfamiliar syntax of printf function

Tags: c, printf

In the source code of Unix fdisk command, I came across following printf.

```
printf ("%s %s %10s %11s %11s %4s %7s ", _("Device"),
        _("Boot"), _("Start"), _("End"), _("Blocks"), _("Id"), _("System"));
```

Why are the strings being placed inside parentheses preceded by an underscore?

Comment: [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a shorthand for `gettext`:

```
#define _(string) gettext (string)
```

**1.1 The Purpose of GNU gettext**

> Usually, programs are written and documented in English, and use
>   English at execution time to interact with users. This is true not
>   only of GNU software, but also of a great deal of proprietary and free
>   software. Using a common language is quite handy for communication
>   between developers, maintainers and users from all countries. On the
>   other hand, most people are less comfortable with English than with
>   their own native language, and would prefer to use their mother tongue
>   for day to day’s work, as far as possible. Many would simply love to
>   see their computer screen showing a lot less of English, and far more
>   of their own language.
>
> However, to many people, this dream might appear so far fetched that
>   they may believe it is not even worth spending time thinking about it.
>   They have no confidence at all that the dream might ever become true.
>   Yet some have not lost hope, and have organized themselves. The
>   Translation Project is a formalization of this hope into a workable
>   structure, which has a good chance to get all of us nearer the
>   achievement of a truly multi-lingual set of programs.
>
> GNU gettext is an important step for the Translation Project, as it is
>   an asset on which we may build many other steps. This package offers
>   to programmers, translators and even users, a well integrated set of
>   tools and documentation. Specifically, the GNU gettext utilities are a
>   set of tools that provides a framework within which other free
>   packages may produce multi-lingual messages.

[More info](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html)